# Orchestra notation and harmony

Tags: orchestra, orchestral-strings, orchestration

For instance I have 3 groups of violins and 3 instruments in each group. I want a clean C major chord from those 3 groups. What's my best choice? To have 1 group play a C, another one an E and the last group to play a G? Or maybe have each group play the chord: 1 instrument C, 2 - E, 3 - G in every group.

What is the most common way it's done?

Comment: Anything which involves one C one E and one G minimum will work. Octaves will make a difference. There's no absolute answer.

Comment: So basically, you have 9 violins playing a chord, so it should be pretty irrelevant which 3 play the C and so on. It would be different if you had 3 violins, 3 violas and 3 cellos, of course.

Comment: How different would it be?

Comment: The notation will be simpler if you go with the first option, so I'd favour that.

Comment: If you had 3 each of violins, violas and cellos, it is much more standard practice to have them playing in unison within each group of 3, rather than having them divided, Conductors will certainly prefer 3 in unison.

Comment: What is defining your 'groups', if it's not the fact that members of the same group play the same thing?

Comment: Just a group of 3 people...  they could anything.

Comment: So do you just mean 'people located close together'?

Comment: @topomorto not exactly together.. well in my situation it's actually not people but rather the instruments themselves. And 1 group is panned 50% left, another in the center, the 3rd one 50% right. They play a C chord in harmony.

Comment: So are you talking about producing  an arrangement with computer (or similar?)

Comment: Yes, but I'm thinking about how it should be played in an orchestra.

Answer (score 1):

If you have three groups and need three notes, I suggest the simple solution!   Your alternatives are div.a 3 within each group or even double stops.  The former won't sound much different, but will complicate the notation.  The latter is a rather different effect.  You gain intensity of sound but lose agility.